# How I can get compiled(?) string in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is code of my test directive:

```
    mymodule.directive("test", function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template:
            '<div data-date="{{avail}}"></div>',
    scope: {
        avail: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.dump = function(el) {
            console.log($('<div>').append(el.clone()).html());
        };
    },
    link: function postLink($scope, $element, $attrs) {            

        $scope.dump($element); // print '<div data-date="{{avail}}"></div>'
        $scope.dump($compile($element)($scope));  // print '<div data-date="{{avail}}"></div>'

        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.dump($element); // print '<div data-date="12.10.2014"></div>'
        }, 1);
    }
}
});
```

The question is: how I can get compiled (or how it names) string

```
<div data-date="12.10.2014"></div>
```

in postLink function (without using setTimeout).

Comment: you cant get compiled

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much like @Ben answered, only you should unregister the $watch listener

```
var unregister = $scope.$watch('avail', function(){
   if($scope.avail) {
       $scope.dump($element);
       unregister();
   }
});
```

Alternatively you can use $timeout

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.dump($element);
})
```

Comment: I didn't know about unregistering in this way, that sounds handy!

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on that:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2480-Unbinding-watch-Listeners-In-AngularJS.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var runOnce = false;

$scope.$watch('avail', function(){
  if($scope.avail && runOnce == false){
    $scope.dump($element);
    runOnce = true;
  }
});
```

The problem you are having is that the link function gets called before the scope value is passed in via the linked attribute. By adding a watch, you can trigger the function you'd like to run when the value has been set - the runOnce flag ensures that this code is only run once. Setting a timeout is less reliable because you can't be sure exactly how many milliseconds will elapse between the link function being called and the scope value being set.

Comment: As far as i understand, function "$watch" adds listener for the "avail". So every time the "avail" changed this code will be executed 'if($scope.avail){ $scope.dump($element); }'

But i only need to call it once inside the directive after every variable in template ("{{avail}}") will be replaced with it's value.

Comment: I updated my answer with some explanation - sorry the first attempt was a bit vague.